# Django- click event doesn't bind to div element

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I've been trying to bind a click event to a div element in an html file, that is part of a Django project. My `menu.html` is as follows-

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Today's menu{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#plus").bind("click", function () {
                $.get("/test/"+this.id+"/", function(data) {
                    if (data.fact_type=="T") {
                         item = data.fact_note;
                    }
                    $('#result')[0].innerHTML=item;
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% for id,image,menu in imageList %}
<div style = "display:inline-block">
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image }}">
    <p>{{ menu }}</p>
    <div id="plus"><span>+</span></div>
    <div id="result">Click to add.</div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This template has been extended from the `base.html` template file, which is-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}
    <hr>
    <p style="display:block>Footer.</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `views.py` function -

```
def order(request, product_id):
    message = {"fact_type": "", "fact_note": ""}
    if request.is_ajax():
        fact = get_object_or_404(Fact, id=fact_id)
        message['fact_type'] = fact.type
        message['fact_note'] = fact.note
    else:
        message = "Error."
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(message), content_type='application/json')
```

But the click event doesn't bind to the div with the id plus. I've tried changing `bind()` to `on()` but with no luck.

Thinking this was caused because the document was probably not being ready, I also tried `$(document).on('click','#plus',function () {  });` , yet it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, is, it is absolutely essential that the *ID*s on a document are  unique. Use a class in conjunction with a unique ID, and your code should work.

Example:

```
{% for id,image,menu in imageList %}

    <div style = "display:inline-block">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image }}">
        <p>{{ menu }}</p>
        <div id="plus-{{id}}" class="plus"><span>+</span></div>
        <div id="result-{{id}}" class="result">Click to add.</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And your script would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".plus").on("click", function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]; // gives you the id
            $.get("/test/"+ id +"/", function(data) {
                if (data.fact_type=="T") {
                     item = data.fact_note;
                }
                $('#result-' + id).html(item); 
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Nope. It is still unclickable. I also tried to hard code the value of the id in the div, but it didn't work either. If the id has to be unique, then shouldn't we also get unique ids to the $(".plus").on("click", function () line as well?

Comment: first off, this was a general idea - next, you dont need the span inside the div now. Also, give a little padding around the plus, so there is more space for the click.

Comment: Did that. No change. I even put that div element outside the for loop and gave it the id '.plus'. Still. no. change.

Comment: Also, "result-{{id}}" is a string. So it won't parse the {{id}}. How do I get the {{id}} to be parsed?

Comment: are you sure `{{id}}` does not get resolved ? It should. Can you paste the resulting HTML in a fiddle, and paste the link here?

Comment: Looks like it does. I thought since it was in quotes, it wouldn't get resolved and would be treated as a string. My bad. Thanks a lot. The click event works now. :-)